# Cant load this JSON into my table

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I 've got a simple thing:

There's a JSON with books objects,every book has a title,author and year.
I would like to choose one option from the list and display chosen property in a table.I've used an example from W3 but right now i'm stuck and nothing works as it should...

[Link's here](http://atomix94.github.io/json-table.github.io)

```
function change_myselect(sel) {
    var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";
    obj = { "table":sel, "limit":20 };
    dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            txt += "<table border='1'>"
            for (x in myObj) {
                txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].name + "</td></tr>";
            }
            txt += "</table>" 
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "generated.json", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("x=" + dbParam);
}
```

Comment: well where is your code that does not work?

Comment: Please provide some code in your question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite easy to spot with a debugger line

```
console.log(myObj)
```

It is an object and you are trying to loop over it. You want to be looping over the key in the object that holds the array.

```
console.log(myObj.books);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over a single property `books` in an object instead of iterating over the array that property contains.

Instead of this:

```
for (x in myObj) {
  txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].name + "</td></tr>";
}
```

try something like this:

```
myObj.books.forEach((book) => {
  txt += "<tr><td>" + book[sel.toLowerCase()] + "</td></tr>";
});
```

Comment: Thank you,now the data is loaded but just the book names,how to achieve display of a year and author when they 're chosen from selection ?

Comment: @Matt Create an object that holds the returned data, with the name as the keys and the book objects as the values. Then when someone clicks on a TD, you can look up the name in the object and display the other properties.

Comment: @Matt - try `book[sel.toLowerCase()]` - answer updated ... this wouldn't need lowercasing if you put the option values in lowercase in the html